# Heroku gem versioning issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler, gemfile

I've been working on an application that runs on Heroku for awhile and occasionally I run into a funny issue where my background workers start failing. It's as if the background workers have an old version of the gem, which used to talk to a HTTP API and was switched to hit a HTTPS endpoint. The gem that's causing problems is written by me and is pulled from Github with the following line in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'stubhub', github: 'Zanfa/stubhub'
```

From my logs, I can see that I'm getting 403s because it tries to hit the non-HTTPS url (which does not exist in the gem anywhere). However when I open the console with `heroku run rails c` and run the job from there, it never has the same issue.

I've also tried `heroku run bundle list` and `bundle list` to compare if there's a mismatch in versions, but it always reports the current version 0.0.23.

And to make things more interesting, this doesn't always happen. There's only like a 20% chance that it will start hitting the non-https endpoint, and doing `heroku restart` usually fixes it, but it will pop up again in a couple of pushes.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Heroku support?

Comment: did you tried "bundle update" before "bundle install" ? . sometimes it helps !

Comment: @igaurav I've added and updated several other gems since, done several `bundle update`, regular `bundle` and `bundle install` calls. It still shows up occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to remember is that every time you do `heroku run` you're instantiating your slug into a new dyno, not interacting with your existing dynos. Googling will show different people dealing with Bundler caching issues, like http://artsy.github.io/blog/2013/01/15/debugging-bundler-issues-with-heroku/

My advice is to push a version of your repo with an empty Gemfile (to clear out the cache) and then push your normal repo again.